# Restrict access to site on subdomain

Tags: multisite, identity-server, login

I have backoffice functionality that should require Sitecore identity server logins with specific permissions/roles. It is hosted on its own Sitecore-site definition and subdomain, for example backoffice.mainsite.com.
I would like to restrict access to the site, requiring users to log in via Sitecore login.

#### Setup

I have tried the following [guide from briancaos](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2017/11/24/sitecore-login-to-website-and-how-to-restrict-access-to-content/) which states to:

- Set `requireLogin` = "true"
- Set the `loginPage` for the site definition

On the backoffice site definition I have set the `loginPage` property to `/identity/login/shell/SitecoreIdentityServer`. Furthermore, I have added the subdomain in `AllowedCorsOriginsGroup2` in `Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml`.

#### Problem

When I attempt to access the site I am correctly redirected to the Sitecore login page. So far, so good.
At this point, I have verified that the `redirect_uri` is pointing to "backoffice.mainsite.com".

From the Sitecore login page I can successfully log in.
Upon successful login I am redirected back to `backoffice.mainsite.com`, which immediately redirects me back to the Sitecore login page.

Back at the Sitecore login page, I have verified that I am indeed logged in:

- I can see the username in the upper right corner of the page
- I can successfully navigate to and browse parent.local/sitecore

However, trying to access any page on `backoffice.mainsite.com` leads me to the Sitecore login page again.

So it seems that while I can successfully log in using the Sitecore login page, I can't actually log in as I cannot access the site. The Sitecore logs do not show any issues.

The site defition is shown below.

```
  <site name="customerserviceportal" patch:before="site[@name='website']"
        inherits="airshoppen-abstract-site-definition"
        hostName="csp.airshoppen.local"
        targetHostName="csp.airshoppen.local"
        language="en"
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/Customer Service Portal/"
        startItem="/Pages/CartSearchPage"
        requireLogin="true"
        domain="sitecore" <-- Added
        loginPage="/sitecore/login" <-- Thanks to @AlinaFodor
  />
  <site name="airshoppen-abstract-site-definition"
        virtualFolder="/"
        physicalFolder="/"
        startItem="/FrontPage"
        database="web"
        domain="extranet"
        allowDebug="true"
        cacheHtml="true"
        htmlCacheSize="50MB"
        enablePreview="true"
        enableWebEdit="true"
        enableDebugger="true"
        disableClientData="false"
        formsRoot="{F1F7AAB6-C8CE-422F-A214-F610C109FA63}"
        scheme="https"
        externalPort="80"
        enableItemLanguageFallback="true"
        enableFieldLanguageFallback="true"
        loginPage ="/"
  />
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is your backoffice site domain Extranet (check site definition domain property), and are you logging in Sitecore with an Extranet or Sitecore user?

Comment: @AlinaFodor The domain is set to "sitecore". I am logging in with the admin user.

Comment: @AlinaFodor I was wrong. The domain was set to "extranet". That said, changing it to "sitecore" did not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change your login page, in site definition like so: `loginPage="/identity/login/[site name from site definition]/SitecoreIdentityServer"` .
Then, you need to configure that all your sites need to use Sitecore Identity Server as Identity Provider.
Edit `\App_Config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config`
Here, you need to uncomment the definition of Identity Provider for all sites, and change it to be Sitecore Identity Server, like so:

```
<!-- An example that maps a sub-provider of the Identity Server to the sites that are not mapped to the SitecoreIdentityServer. -->
 <mapEntry name="all sites">
          <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
           <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='SitecoreIdentityServer']" id="SitecoreIdentityServer" />
          </identityProviders>
  </mapEntry>
```

In same config file, at the bottom, add you site definition login page like so:

```
<site name="[site name from site definition]" set:loginPage="$(loginPath)[site name from site definition]/SitecoreIdentityServer" />
    </sites>
```

Comment: That worked insofar as it allows me to log in. It takes me to the Sitecore Launchpad, however. I have updated the post with the site definition (including your change).

Comment: @sgu to protect a site for visitors and authenticate visitors with Sitecore identity server you need to follow Sitecore documentation: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/en/understanding-sitecore-authentication-behavior-changes.html. By default Sitecore Identity Server is used for access to backend (context site: shell). Please see above answer updated with required changes

Comment: Those changes seems to have done the trick. Although I have also added `csp.airshoppen.local` to `AllowedCorsOriginsGroup2` in `Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml`. I can't figure out if that it required or not.